# How can I remove the new line tag from python when printing it to a textarea?

Tags: django, textarea, robots.txt

So I have this text area:

```
<textarea id="input_txt" name="file_txt" class="input_size" rows="5"
  form="store" style="font-size: 11pt;"
  default_text="">{{store.robots_txt|default:robots}}</textarea>
```

But the thing is that when I print the txt it prints like this.

> ['User-agent: *\n', 'Disallow: /something/\n', 'Disallow: /b/\n',
>   'Disallow: /something/\n', 'Disallow: /something\n', 'Disallow:
>   /something\n']

And I want something like this in the textarea:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /something/
Disallow: /something/
Disallow: /something/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `default` behavior in tags:

`{{store.file|default:"mydefault.txt"}}`

If you need to *load* that text file, it should be loaded in your view and passed as a parameter to the response's `context`.

Comment: How do you tell the tag the file address, the file is not in the DB it's a static file

Comment: You're saying you want to load and print whatever was put in?

Comment: Yes the text file to be printed in the text area.

Comment: Well, you aren't going to be able to do that with a template tag; you need to pass in the data into the context

Comment: Oh ok I guess I'll add it to my view then pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Ok I got it in the context but now i need to figure out how to make it look as a new line when theirs enters and not \n